# Run Python scripts without explicitly invoking `python`

Tags: linux, python

I'm using Debian Linux.

I was wondering if there was a way to configure to run *all* Python scripts in the terminal by typing `script.py` (instead of `python script.py`).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

- Make sure the file is executable: `chmod +x script.py`
- Use a shebang to let the kernel know what interpreter to use.  The top line of the script should read:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  ```

  This assumes that your script will run with the default python.  If you need a specific version, just specify in the shebang:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python2.7
  ```

Now you can type:

```
    ./script.py
```

if the script is in your current directory, or:

```
    script.py
```

if the location of the script happens to be in your PATH, or:

```
    path/to/script.py
```

otherwise.

Comment: Generally it's a better idea to use `#!/usr/bin/env python`, in case the user has a local build of python (eg, in `/usr/local/bin`) which they'd rather run the script with.

Comment: @sapi Not according to Debian it isn't, at least in their dev policies.  If you are writing your own scripts, you can accept the risk of course, it is just better to be explicit.  If you want the local one, choose it in the shebang.

Comment: It's not `bash` that reads the file when executing...

Comment: @progo This is true - note that if you see an answer that you think would benefit from improvement, go ahead and edit it, improvements are always welcome

Comment: And you'll have to do `./script.py`, not `script.py`

Comment: @PaulDraper Please see the previous reply.  If you have a suggested improvement to an answer, go ahead and edit the answer.

Comment: @sapi: I agree.  Plus, if you install multiple pythons, you can generally guess right:  `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`

Comment: @PaulDraper The question is totally right. U only have to use `./` to execute if the script is not in your PATH. If the script is in another path or you just want to use full path you don't need `./`'. Also, the whole .py naming can be avoided, is not a must.

Answer (score 34):

Under linux you can simply use the hashbang(aka shebang). Add the line

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

if you want to execute the default python interpreter.

```
#!/path/to/python[x.x]
```

to use some specific version, or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If you want the environment to find python for you.

You will also be required to make the script executable

```
chmod +x script[.py]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This will ensure that the python the user expects to be used will be the one that runs the script. This is especially important if the user is using virtualenv to have a specific version of python in a given environment.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shebang line at top of your script as below:

## !/usr/bin/python

Update appropriate python version on which you want to execute the script.
e.g. For python 3.6 its

## !/usr/bin/python3.6

for default interpreter

## !/usr/bin/python

Note: Make sure script has executable permission.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the top of the script to run default python interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

To specify the python version then add the version number after python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

If you have a local build of python and would like to use that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then you will need to make your script executable by running the following command:

```
chmod +x script.py
```

To run the script:

```
./script.py
```